# How to add ListView and tab bar in android

Tags: android, listview, tabbar

I want the list view and tab bar both at the same time and my code is below:

Please check my Main Activity and Custom Adapter and tell me what changes I need to do.
Because list is working but tabs are not being displayed.

Two XML files I have included.
1.tab_bar
2.final_tab_item

Please let me know where I am going wrong...

```
 MainActivity.java



 package com.example.tabwithlist;



    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import com.example.customlist.CustomAdapter;
    import com.example.customlist.ListModel;

    import android.app.TabActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;

    public class MainActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener 

    {
        ListView list;
        CustomAdapter adapter;

        public  ArrayList<ListModel> CustomListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<ListModel>();

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
          TabHost tabHost;

          @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.tab_bar);
           //   setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_view);

             setListData();

                Resources res =getResources(); 
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listnew);

                //**************** Create Custom Adapter *********//*
                adapter=new CustomAdapter(this, CustomListViewValuesArr,res);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);


                for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

                    final ListModel sched = new ListModel();

                     //******* Firstly take data in model object ******//*
                       sched.setCompanyName("Company "+i);
                       sched.setImage("image"+i);
                       sched.setUrl("http:\\\\www."+i+".com");

                    //******** Take Model Object in ArrayList **********//*
                    CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched);
                }

           //    Get TabHost Refference
              tabHost = getTabHost();

              // Set TabChangeListener called when tab changed
              tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

              TabHost.TabSpec spec;
              Intent intent;
              //************* TAB1 ************//*
              // Create  Intents to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
              intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1.class);
              spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator("")
                            .setContent(intent);

              //Add intent to tab
              tabHost.addTab(spec);

              //************* TAB2 ************//*
              intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab2.class);
              spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second").setIndicator("")
                            .setContent(intent);  
              tabHost.addTab(spec);

              /************* TAB3 ************/
              intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab3.class);
              spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third").setIndicator("")
                            .setContent(intent);
              tabHost.addTab(spec);

              // Set drawable images to tab
              tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab2);
              tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab3);

              // Set Tab1 as Default tab and change image   
              tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
              tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab1_over);


           }

      private void setListData() {

            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

                final ListModel sched = new ListModel();

                  /******* Firstly take data in model object ******/
                   sched.setCompanyName("Company "+i);
                   sched.setImage("image"+i);
                   sched.setUrl("http:\\\\www."+i+".com");

                /******** Take Model Object in ArrayList **********/
                CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched);
            }

        }


    @Override

        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

        /************ Called when tab changed *************/

            //********* Check current selected tab and change according images *******/

            for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
            {
                if(i==0)
                    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab1);
                else if(i==1)
                    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab2);
                else if(i==2)
                    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab3);
            }


            Log.i("tabs", "CurrentTab: "+tabHost.getCurrentTab());

            if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==0)
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab1_over);
            else if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==1)
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab2_over);
            else if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==2)
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab3_over);

        }
    }


    CustomAdapter.java(Here I am inflating my final_tab_item.xml file which displays how list view will look like.)

    package com.example.customlist;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.R;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    //import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {



        /*********** Declare Used Variables *********/

        private Activity activity;
        private ArrayList data;
        private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
        public Resources res;
        ListModel tempValues=null;
        int i=0;

        /*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
        public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d,Resources resLocal) {

            /********** Take passed values **********/
            activity = a;
            data=d;
            res = resLocal;

            /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () **********************/
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        /******** What is the size of Passed Arraylist Size ************/
        public int getCount() {

            if(data.size()<=0)
                return 1;
            return data.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        /********* Create a holder to contain inflated xml file elements ***********/
        public static class ViewHolder{

            public TextView text;
            public TextView text1;
            public TextView textWide;
            public ImageView image;

        }

        /*********** Depends upon data size called for each row , Create each ListView row ***********/
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View vi=convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView==null){ 

                /********** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
               //vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout., null); 
                vi=inflater.inflate(com.example.tabwithlist.R.layout.final_tab_item,null);

                /******** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ************/

                holder=new ViewHolder();
                holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(com.example.tabwithlist.R.id.text);
                holder.text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(com.example.tabwithlist.R.id.text1);
                holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(com.example.tabwithlist.R.id.image);




               /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
                vi.setTag(holder);
            }
            else  
                holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

            if(data.size()<=0)
            {
                holder.text.setText("No Data");

            }
            else
            {
                /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
                tempValues=null;
                tempValues = (ListModel) data.get(position);

                /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/
                 holder.text.setText(tempValues.getCompanyName());
                 holder.text1.setText(tempValues.getUrl());
                 holder.image.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier("com.example.tabwithlist:drawable/"+tempValues.getImage(),null,null));

                 /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row ***********/
              //   vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
            }
            return vi;
        }
        }


    tab_bar.xml(In this file I am declaring list view and tab bar)

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabHost 
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listnew"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            /> 

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ur MainActivity  loads the tabs only, put our listview code in first tab (Tab1.class)

Changes:

tab_bar.xml with

```
<TabHost 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

remove all the listview code from ur MainActivity.

Create Tab1, Tab2 and Tab3 activities.
Create new xml add

```
 <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listnew"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            />
```

Move all the listview code to Tab1.java

Comment: but my tabs are not displaying

Comment: remove all the listview code from MainActivity and created all the listview code in TAB1.java and created new XML with only listview and refernced that in TAB1.java.... but still tabs are not displayed ..only listview is visible